# What is the difference between Shrink and Compact in SQL Server CE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have a method that is run periodically to optimise my application's SQL Server Compact Edition (3.5) database. The existing code uses the Shrink() method:

```
        SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(dbConnectionString);
        engine.Shrink();
```

Today I noticed that there's also a Compact() method. Which is preferable for periodic maintenance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [SQL Server Compact Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/10/26/sqlceengine-issceengine-shrink-vs-repair.aspx):

> The difference between these two is
>   much similar to Internal and External
>   Memory Fragmentation.
>
> From [SqlCeEngine.Shrink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.shrink.aspx) documentation,
>
> Reclaims wasted space in the database
>   by moving empty and unallocated pages
>   to the end of the file, and then
>   truncating the file.  You can
>   configure a database to automatically
>   shrink by setting the autoshrink
>   threshold option in connection string.
>   Shrink does not create a temporary
>   database file.
>
> From [SqlCeEngine.Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.compact.aspx) documentation,
>
> Reclaims wasted space in the database
>   by creating a new database file from
>   the existing file.  By creating a new
>   database means, it reclaims the free
>   space between rows.
>
> To be more clear, Shrink claims the
>   pages which are entirely free or
>   unallocated; where as, Compact claims
>   the wasted space with in the page too.
>   Hence Compact requires creating a new
>   database file.