# shrink or compact in Sql Server CE?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I am using Visual Studio 2008. and i am new at sqlce.I am checking sdf file and if sdf doesnt exist,I  create and then insert around 5000 rows to my sqlce db.If sdf exists,first i delete all tables's rows and then insert these records to existed tables.After insert complete,i am compacting database.By the way,compacting lasts about 13 seconds.I know a method that calls Shrink.Shrink and Compact make db smaller but in this scenerio which of them should i use?How can i make compacting withing shorter time?I dont need backup of sdf and after compact,i delete old sdf.i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707625/what-is-the-difference-between-shrink-and-compact-in-sql-server-ce) topic but couldnt decide which i should use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please see:

- [What is the difference between Shrink and Compact in SQL Server CE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707625/what-is-the-difference-between-shrink-and-compact-in-sql-server-ce)

which quotes from the [SQL Server Compact Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/10/26/sqlceengine-issceengine-shrink-vs-repair.aspx):

> **SqlCeEngine/ISSCEEngine: Shrink Vs Compact**   The difference between
>   these two is much similar to Internal
>   and External Memory Fragmentation.
>
> From [SqlCeEngine.Shrink documentation](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.shrink.aspx):
>
> Reclaims wasted space in the database
>   by moving empty and unallocated pages
>   to the end of the file, and then
>   truncating the file.  You can
>   configure a database to automatically
>   shrink by setting the autoshrink
>   threshold option in connection string.
>   Shrink does not create a temporary
>   database file.
>
> From [SqlCeEngine.Compact documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.compact.aspx):
>
> Reclaims wasted space in the database
>   by creating a new database file from
>   the existing file.  By creating a new
>   database means, it reclaims the free
>   space between rows.
>
> To be more clear, Shrink claims the
>   pages which are entirely free or
>   unallocated; where as, Compact claims
>   the wasted space with in the page too.
>   Hence Compact requires creating a new
>   database file.
>
> Empty space with in the page could be
>   as result of:
>
> 1) If there were 5 rows in a page
>   and two of them are deleted
>
> 2)  If there was a row in the middle of the
>   page which on update required more
>   space, has moved out of the page (Ex:
>   nvarchar column update)
>
> Empty pages and unallocated pages
>   could remain in database as a result
>   of:
>
> 1)      All rows in a page are deleted
>
> 2)      Whole table is dropped